# How to sum repeated elements in an array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays.  The first is `array_impuestos` which is the tax names.  The second is `array_impuestos_valor` which contains the corresponding tax values. The tax value for the tax name at index `0` of `array_impuestos` would be the value at index `0` of `array_impuestos_valor`.

I need to detect which elements are repeated in `array_impuestos` and sum the corresponding values in `array_impuestos_valor`.

For example, `'iva.21%'` appears twice in `array_impuestos` corresponding to both `'21'` and `'10.5'` in `array_impuesto_valor`.
I need to sum those last 2 values.

```js
array_impuestos = ["iva.21%", "irfp.-7%", "iva.21%"];
array_impuestos_valor = ["21", "3.5", "10.5"];

array_impuestos.forEach(function (elemento1, indice1, array1) {
  nombre1 = elemento1;
  indice1 = indice1;
  array_impuestos_valor.forEach(function (elemento2, indice2, array2) {
    if (indice1 == indice2) {
      impuesto_repetido = (array_impuestos.indexOf(elemento1) === indice1);
      if (impuesto_repetido == false) {
        //I don't know how to continue sincerely
        console.log(nombre1 + '  ' + elemento2);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this, group the `array_impuestos_valor` values according to their corresponding `array_impuestos` values.

```js
let array_impuestos=["iva.21%","irfp.-7%","iva.21%"];
let array_impuestos_valor=["21","3.5","10.5"];

const hash_sum = {};
for(let i=0; i<array_impuestos.length; i++){
    if(!hash_sum[array_impuestos[i]])
    hash_sum[array_impuestos[i]] = +array_impuestos_valor[i];
    else
    hash_sum[array_impuestos[i]] += +array_impuestos_valor[i];
}

console.log(hash_sum);

array_impuestos = [];
array_impuestos_valor = [];

// 1st method
for(const x in hash_sum){
    array_impuestos.push(x);
    array_impuestos_valor.push(hash_sum[x]);
}

console.log(array_impuestos, array_impuestos_valor);

// 2nd method
console.log(Object.keys(hash_sum), Object.values(hash_sum));
```

Comment: Use `Object.values(hash_sum)` or `Object.keys(hash_sum)` depending on whether you want an array of names or values.

Comment: hello your answer helped me a lot, I would like to know some way to be able to traverse the array type object

Comment: you can use what @GirkovArpa mentioned

Comment: or you can use for in loop https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Comment: I have added to my answer both the approaches @DavidRobles

Comment: the best internet community without a doubt, thank you very much friends

Answer (score 2):

Here's a more functional solution:

```js
const nombres = ['iva.21%', 'irfp.-7%', 'iva.21%'];
const valores = ['21', '3.5', '10.5'];

const impuestos = nombres.reduce((impuestos, nombre, i) => {
  impuestos[nombre] = (impuestos[nombre] || 0) + +valores[i];
  return impuestos;
}, {});

console.log(impuestos); // { 'iva.21%': 31.5, 'irfp.-7%': 3.5 }
```

Answer (score 1):

this should work (making use of the concept of `object` in JS to build a `map`)

```js
let array_impuestos=["iva.21%","irfp.-7%","iva.21%"];
let array_impuestos_valor=["21","3.5","10.5"];
let res = {};
for(let  i = 0; i < array_impuestos.length; i++)
     res[array_impuestos[i]] = +array_impuestos_valor[i] + (res[array_impuestos[i]] ? res[array_impuestos[i]] : 0)
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let array_impuestos=["iva.21%","irfp.-7%","iva.21%"];
let array_impuestos_valor=["21","3.5","10.5"];

for(let i=0;i<array_impuestos.length;i++){
   console.log(calculation(array_impuestos[i]))
}

function calculation(key){
    let arr = []
    let sum = []
    let total = 0
    array_impuestos.forEach(function(item,index){
        if(item == key) {
            arr.push({key:item,index:index})
        }
    })

for(let item of arr){
    sum.push(array_impuestos_valor[item.index])
}

//performing sum
for(let i=0;i<sum.length;i++){
    total += parseFloat(sum[i])
}
return total
}
```